# HTML Email Image/Product name issues in Outlook PC

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I am running into an issue with Outlook PC not wanting to place nicely with my product images and product names.

Across all other email clients we have tested, the names appear below the products as we expected, however with Outlook PC we are getting the product names bumping up next to the image like this - 
[Product names next to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tahUO.png)

My question is how do we make it stop? Haha. I have included the code for one of the products to show what we are doing, but have removed links to our site for obvious reasons.

```
<!-- Product 1 --> 
    <td valign="top" align="center" class="product-image-wrapper" style="display: block; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'MS Serif', 'New York', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, 'Open Sans'; width: 25%; padding-bottom: 20px; margin: 0;">
      <a href="#" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'MS Serif', 'New York', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, 'Open Sans'; text-align: center; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: 300; width: 100%; display: block; color: #53565a; text-decoration: none; margin: 0; font-size: 10px;">
        <span style="font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'MS Serif', 'New York', Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, 'Open Sans'; width: 146px; height: 146px; display: block; margin: 0 auto 5px; border: 1px solid #edeeee;"> 
          <img src="http://placehold.it/146" alt="Place Holder Image" width="146" style="display: block; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto !important; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: 146px; margin: 0 auto; border: 0;" />
        </span>
          First Christmas Personalized Ornament
      </a>
    </td>
<!-- // End Product 1 -->
```

I'm thinking the text needs to be wrapped up in something, but I'm just not sure what or how. So any advice, tips, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need anymore details from me on what the code looks like. With HTML emails being inlined, most all of our styling is right there, other than some mobile specific stuff.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you put "First Christmas Personalized Ornament" text in span element and add style="display:block;" to the span, it will be fixed.

Atakan.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply! I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @CP_Clap Np, I hope its work. If its not, forward your test email to me and I check again.